# What are the commands to enable V8Js PHP extension on linux vagrant?

Tags: php, reactjs, debian, server-side-rendering, v8js

How to add V8js PHP extension on linux, so that I could use reactjs in PHP app? In one video tutorial, 4 steps were mentioned

- Build and install v8
- Build and install php-v8js
- Enable the v8js extension in php
- extension=v8js.so in php.ini

Like in windows we can download and copy-paste the .dll files, I am not sure if the .iso format is used and enabled by commands only. 
Please guide.